# Difference between the_permalink() and get_permalink() function

Tags: functions, permalinks

In WordPress I am using both `the_permalink()` and `get_permalink()` functions, but I cannot get any difference in the output of both functions. What is the difference between both functions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`the_permalink` echos out the permalink of the current post to the frontend.

`get_permalink` however returns it as a variable, but does not echo it out. You can also pass a post ID to it if you want the permalink of another post.

`the_permalink` is equivalent to:

```
echo get_permalink();
```

Which is very close to what it actually does. This is the implementation of `the_permalink`:

```
function the_permalink() {
    echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() ) );
}
```

Comment: It means all the functions like the_ID() and get_ID() also have same differences like this. Sorry but i am new to wordpress that's why asking

Comment: @AliasgerSW thats the pattern, there are some exceptions, but generally it is that way

Comment: @AliasgerSW when in doubt, look at the code. [QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com) is a great site for looking up the source code of WordPress functions.

Comment: @ AliasgerSW it's made by our very own @Rarst

Comment: @shea QueryPosts is retired. :-(\

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) on this you will see that `get_permalink()` is there for use outside the loop. `the_permalink()` is for use within the loop. That’s the easiest way to look at it.

Comment: might be the easy way to look at it, but not a very complete one

Comment: For sure, @Tom J Nowell♦ answer is much more concise. Much better and well explained :-)

Answer (score -1):

`the_permalink()` is used in posts loops, like `the_title()`. Read more about loops in *[The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)*.

`get_permalink()` can be used in loops or outside the loops. In the loops, the function returns (not echo) the current post permalink. But outside loops, it requires a post ID.

For example:

```
echo get_permalink( 1 );
```

This will display the current page permalink:

```
echo get_permalink();
```

Comment: actually it doesn't require an ID outside the loop